# Correctly encoding of string

Tags: c#, encoding

i need to correctly encode the string:

```
string Nazev="TriŔko Chevak";
```

I need this:

```
string Nazev="Tričko Chevak";
```

I try this, but no change:

```
Encoding win = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);
Encoding z = Encoding.Default;
byte[] zBytes = z.GetBytes(Nazev);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(z, win, zBytes);
Nazev = win.GetString(isoBytes);
```

Have you any ideas?

I open *.DBF file and load values to datatable:

```
string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(NovyNazevCSV) + ";Extended Properties=\"dBASE IV;Text;CharacterSet=1250;\"";
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                var sql = "select * from " + Path.GetFileName(NovyNazevCSV);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dtBush);
            }
foreach (DataRow radekBush in dtBush.Rows) 
{
Nazev = radekBush[3].ToString();
}
```

In file i have:
Tričko but in datatable i have TriŔko...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is there an error message? If so include that in your question.

Comment: For someone who isn't accustomed to that local, could you explain why you would expect that conversion? I personally have never seen Ŕ mean the same thing as č.

Comment: Why do you think that string isn't encoded correctly? .NET uses UTF-16 which supports those characters.

Comment: I edited first post...

Comment: What is `Encoding.Default`? Are you sure that's not the same as 1250 on your system? Anyway, you should never use `Encoding.Default`.

Comment: This will be solved by setting the correct character set in your connection string per the duplicate.  The fact you're getting the wrong characters means that your current setting of 1250 is incorrect.

Comment: Encoding and decoding transforms between bytes and strings (encoding is string to bytes, decoding is bytes to string). The fact that you already have it as a string indicates that it has already been decoded. Decoding is potentially a lossy process depending on the encoding chosen. You should go back to whatever produced the original text and ensure it outputs the correct bytes instead of trying to fix it when you have it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding.Default` will return default ANSI encoding, try using `UTF-8` encoding instead:

```
...
Encoding z = Encoding.UTF8;
...
```

Also you might want to try using `CharacterSet=65001` in your connection string.

Comment: I try this, but still the same :/